# Is it possible to capture the portion(i.e. particular view) of the screen?

Tags: android, screen-capture, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

Just like iOS Screen Capture View, is it possible to capture the portion(i.e. particular view) of the screen?

Comment: Not using the media projection APIs, which I assume is what you are using, given your choice of tags.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I have tried to use Media Projection APIs. Any suggestion to meet the requirement(if feasible in android)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Any suggestion or guidance will be very helpful

Comment: If you are trying to capture the screen of arbitrary apps, you do not have any really good way of knowing where on the screen any of the widgets are. If you are trying to capture the contents of some widget of yours in some activity of yours, have that widget draw itself to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am trying to capture contents of my activity only. Basically, I am having a video view on the portion of the screen and need to draw annotation(like line, rectangle) over the video to prepare a video with annotation.

Comment: I don't think that you can use the "draw itself to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`" approach with `VideoView`. But, if it is your own activity, and you can capture the `VideoView` with the media projection APIs (as I haven't tried that combination), since you know where the `VideoView` is on the screen, crop the screenshot yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I need to prepare a video not screenshot

Comment: IMHO, you don't annotate a video by capturing a screencast. Instead, you need to manipulate the video frames, putting your overlay into the actual video itself, using `ffmpeg` or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try.